# »zieht in der Sache«

Tags: meaning-in-context

Ein Zitat aus n24.de:

> Innenminister Thomas de Maizière (CDU), der schon am Dienstag auf
>   einer Klausurtagung des Fraktionsvorstands hinter verschlossenen Türen
>   die Pläne seines Ministeriums erläutert, fand dafür Beifall von den
>   führenden Innenpolitikern. Sein Argument, mit einem
>   Einwanderungsgesetz sei Flüchtlingen nicht gedient, **zieht in der
>   Sache.** Allerdings wäre man damit den Sozialdemokraten
>   entgegengekommen, die sich schon Anfang der Woche erneut auf ein
>   Einwanderungsgesetz festlegt hatten.

Was bedeutet in diesem Zusammenhang der Ausdruck *zieht in der Sache*? Wie kann man ihn sinngetreu umformulieren?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die ganze Phrase ist

> Sein Argument zieht in der Sache.

Dies ist gleichbedeutend mit:

> Sein Argument zieht vom Sachverhalt her.
>
> Sein Argument ist sachlich gesehen zutreffend.

Das *in der Sache* wird verwendet, um abzugrenzen. Zwar ist das Argument im Sachverhalt richtig, aber andere Faktoren werden dadurch erschwert oder ausgeblendet. Namentlich wird eine Diskrepanz zu den Sozialdemokraten geschaffen.

Comment: Danke, jetzt ist alles klar :)